# When to use "huge" and "big"

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives

What is the difference between *huge* and *big*?

For example:

> - He made a huge difference to the team.
>     He made a big difference to the team.

Is there a difference in meaning?

Comment: *Huge* is bigger than *big*. *Huge* is *very* big.

Comment: @TrevorD ok that means when i say `he made a huge difference to the team` it means it is very big part and when i say `he made a big difference to the team` it is just a big part of it

Comment: Yes. If you are actually *saying* the words (not just writing them), people sometimes say *huge difference* when being 'polite'. But in that case (in British usage), emphasis on the words can make a difference. If you say *He made a HUGE difference ...* with the emphasis on "HUGE", you are emphasising his contribution as bigger than others, but if you just say *He made a huge difference ...* with no extra emphasis on "huge", then it's just 'polite'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I'm posting my previous comments as an answer as that seems to have been accepted by OP.]

***Huge*** is bigger than ***big***: ***huge*** means ***very big***.

But ***huge*** can sometimes be used 'politely' just to mean *big*.
For example, if you were to *read* the expression:

> *He made a huge difference to the team*

you might well think he had made a bigger difference to the team than did many of his colleagues.
On the other hand, if someone were to *speak* those words (e.g. at a farewell presentation), the meaning may well depend on the emphasis of the speaker.
If the speaker says:

> *He made a **huge** difference ...*

with the emphasis on "huge", he would most likely be emphasising that the person's contribution was indeed bigger than that of others. But if he just says:

> *He made a huge difference ...*

with no extra emphasis on "huge", then he is probably just being 'polite'.